# Django update modelform with field constraints

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Having the following Model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    author = models.CharField()
    date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'author')

class BookSerializerWrite(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book

class BookView(ApiView):

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = BookSerializerWrite(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
```

The view above does not work as the `serializer.is_valid()` is `False`.
The message is:

```
'The fields name, author must make a unique set'
```

Which is the constraint of the model.

**How do I update the model?**

I would rather not override the serializer's validation method.

I also cannot access the `validated_data` for an update as in

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

as this is empty due to the fact that the form does not validate. 
Is there a builtin solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using `UpdateAPIview`

## serializers.py

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name', 'author', 'date')
```

## views.py

```
from rest_framework.generics import UpdateAPIview
from .serializers import BookSerializer

class BookUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
   serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

url_patterns = [
    path('api/book/<int:pk>/update/', views.BookUpdateView.as_view(), name="book_update"),
]
```

Now, post your data to above url. It should work.

Reference: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py